# Deciphering Unclear Syntax

Tags: c++, syntax

I ran into this the code below while looking through another programmer's work. I am not new to C++, but I can't figure out what this code is supposed to do.

So my question is: 
What is this line of code supposed to do assuming it is syntactically correct?

```
int type, ht, minht = this->maxDepth+1, mini = -1 ;
```

Comment: Looks like you *are* new to C++.

Comment: A 2 minute test program would answer this question.

Comment: Note:  the `this->` syntax is only valid for methods inside a `struct` or `class`.

Comment: I don't understand the close requests for too broad. It seems a very specific question to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It creates four variables and is shortened version of this:

```
int type;
int ht;
int minht = this->maxDepth + 1;
int mini = -1;
```

Comment: I see how obvious it is now that I look at your answer. Thank you for the help.